# how to keep fractions in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I got a numpy array which contains some fractions.
When I generate a dataframe from this array, the fractions turned into floats.
How do I still keep all the fractions in the dataframe?
My code is something like this:

```
row=["A","B"]
col=["X1","X2"]
my_array=np.array([[1/3,2/5],[4/7,1/6]])
df = pd.DataFrame(data = my_array, 
                index = row, 
                columns = col)
print(my_array)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
[[1/3 2/5]
[4/7 1/6]]
         X1        X2
A  0.333333  0.400000
B  0.571429  0.166667
```

Comment: But `1/3` **is** a float... nothing's being changed here...

Comment: You cannot, eventually use `Fraction` objects (but you'll lose vectorization), or use two columns, one for the numerator, one for the denominator

Comment: Btw, I don't know in which context you can get the provided output for `my_array`, the output must be `[[0.33333333 0.4       ] [0.57142857 0.16666667]]`

Comment: a pandas user might investigate this along the lines of: Is there an extension array type for  fractions? Maybe in some library?

Comment: I use np.set_printoptions(formatter={'all':lambda x: str(fractions.Fraction(x).limit_denominator())}) for keeping fraction in the array     
@mozway

Comment: OK, so you don't keep the fractions, **you simulate having fractions** when you print ;) This doesn't improve the precisions

Answer (score 0):

<s>You can use [`Rational`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#rational) from the `sympy` package:</s>

EDIT: You can use the built in [`Fraction`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) as suggested in the comments.  Also, as noted in the comments, this might make your formatted output friendlier, but you will lose the benefit of vectorization (your code will go slower).

```
import pandas as pd
from fractions import Fraction
my_array=np.array([[1/3,2/5],[4/7,1/6]])
row=["A","B"]
col=["X1","X2"]
data=[[Fraction(1,3), Fraction(2,5)],[Fraction(4,7),Fraction(1,6)]]
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data = data, 
    index = row, 
    columns = col
)
```

Output:

```
    X1   X2
A  1/3  2/5
B  4/7  1/6
```

Comment: But like `Fractions` you'll need to use an object dtype and will lose benefit of vectorization

Comment: you can also use python standard module `fractions` instead of 3rd party library so `from fractions import Fraction`